# coercion to interface with methods having multiple parameters

Tags: groovy, coercion

Let's say I've got such interface

```
interface IFile {
    void writeFile(String name, byte[] bytes)
    byte[] readFile(String name)
}
```

How to do a coercion to that interface?
Because so far that approach does not work and leads to compilation exception

```
def fileCoeImp = { 
    name, bytes -> new File(nane) << bytes,  
    name -> new File(name).getBytes()
} as IFile
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a map:

```
def fileCoeImp = [
    writeFile : { name, bytes -> new File(name) << bytes },  
    readFile : { name -> new File(name).getBytes() }
] as IFile
```